# googleapiclient.errors.HttpError - returned "field [name] has issue [Invalid project resource name]" in python3 but not python2

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-api-client

I am getting an HttpError when running my code with python3, but not when I am running with python2. The code is taken from [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine-sample/blob/master/gce/cloud_handler.py) repo.

The error occurs when I am writing logs, with the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/me/project/gce/cloud_handler.py", line 163, in write_log
.execute(http=http)
File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 851, in execute
raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting
```

https://logging.googleapis.com/v1beta3/projects/b%27myprojectid%27/logs/task_runner/entries:write?alt=json

```
returned "field [name] has issue [Invalid project resource name]">
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

```py
    def write_log(self, record):

        {...}
        try:
            print(type(self.client))
            resp = self.client.projects().logs().entries().write(
                projectsId=self.project_id,
                logsId=self.logname,
                body=body)\
                .execute(http=http)  #ERROR HAPPENS HERE

        except Exception as e:
            sys.stderr.write(e.message + '\n')
```

Comment: Where is this code being run? Can you confirm that `self.project_id` is getting set correctly?